# How do I pivot query using UNION ALL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table structure & below is the Query i am executing :-

Following are the tables :-

**First Table :-**

[image]

**Second Table :-**

[image]

```
SELECT Code, Fname, OTHINC1, OTHINC2
FROM (SELECT a.FieldName
            ,a.YearlyValue
            ,b.Code
            ,b.Fname
      FROM [TaxOtherIncome] AS a
      INNER JOIN [EmployeeDetail] AS b
         ON a.EmployeeId = b.Id
      WHERE a.EntryDate = '2014-12-01') x
      PIVOT (MAX(YearlyValue) FOR FieldName IN (OTHINC1,OTHINC2)) p
```

Result i am getting :-

[image]

I also want Records from the Second table i mentioned above. So In my final Result Columns `SUBFLD36` 
`SUBFLD37`  & `House_Rent`  will be added.

As i am new to Pivot, Help me to modify above query to get expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT Code, Fname, OTHINC1, OTHINC2, SUBFLD36, SUBFLD37, House_Rent
FROM (SELECT a.FieldName
            ,a.YearlyValue
            ,b.Code
            ,b.Fname
      FROM [TaxOtherIncome] AS a
      INNER JOIN [EmployeeDetail] AS b
         ON a.EmployeeId = b.Id
      WHERE a.EntryDate = '2014-12-01'
      UNION
      SELECT a.FieldName
            ,a.FieldValue AS YearlyValue
            ,a.EmployeeCode AS Code
            ,b.Fname
      FROM SecondTable AS a
      INNER JOIN [EmployeeDetail] AS b
         ON a.EmployeeId = b.Id
      WHERE EntryDate = '2014-12-01') x
      PIVOT (MAX(YearlyValue) FOR FieldName IN (OTHINC1, OTHINC2, SUBFLD36, SUBFLD37, House_Rent)) p
```

Comment: I don't know where you get `YearlyValue` and `Fname` from the second table.

Comment: I get `YearlyValue` from Table 1 as you can see in above image....`Fname` i am getting from `[EmployeeDetail]` table.

Comment: I've edited my answer but about `YearlyValue`, you don't have it  in the second table according to the screenshot.

Comment: In the second table it is `FieldValue`.

Comment: There you go. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66731/discussion-between-king-code-and-anup).

Answer (score 4):

Consider you are inserting the result after your join to a temporary table which is the below

[image]

Declare a variable for getting the columns to pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + [FIELD NAME] + ']', 
               '[' + [FIELD NAME] + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [FIELD NAME] FROM #TEMP) PV  
               ORDER BY [FIELD NAME]
```

Now pivot it

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @query = '           
                  SELECT * FROM 
                 (
                     SELECT * FROM #TEMP
                 ) x
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                     MAX([YEARLY VALUE])
                     FOR [FIELD NAME] IN (' + @cols + ')
                ) p      

                '     
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

[Click here to view the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68b24/1)

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Here you can do it dynamically ie, 'OTHINC1,2...may be dynamic. So need to pivoting dynamically. Please feel free to ask me for any clarification :) @Anup

Comment: In your fiddle, i can only see `OTHINC1` & `OTHINC2` columns...I need `SUBFLD36, SUBFLD37, House_Rent` columns also..

Comment: Apply UNION ALL to get data from the other table ie, for column CODE you need to get fro EMPLOYEECODE column, for FName you need to get data from FIELDNAME column @Anup